# Can the product of absolutely converging sequences diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series, infinite-product

Let $a_n, b_n$ be $2$ sequences with the property that $\sum |a_n|$ and $\sum |b_n|$ are something, that is, the sums converge. Is it possible that $\sum a_n b_n$ diverges?

If I didn't put absolute values around the sums then you have this obvious example:
$a_n = b_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ with the product being the Harmonic Series.

Comment: no they cannot.

Comment: why did you write the same series twice?

Comment: woops. Will fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For large $n$, $|a_n|\geq a_n^2,|b_n|\geq b_n^2$ therefore $ \sum_{n}a_n^2<\infty$ and $\sum_{n}b_n^2<\infty$.

Now, using Cauchy Schwarz, the result follows namely

$$  \sum_{n}a_nb_n \leq \sqrt{  \sum_{n}a_n^2       }  \sqrt{  \sum_{n}b_n^2       }  <\infty $$

Answer (score 6):

No, $\sum a_n b_n$ will be absolutely convergent: since $\sum b_n$ converges, then $b_n \to 0$, so $b_n$ is bounded.

Comment: And in fact Abel's test says that without assuming $\sum b_n$ converges, just boundedness and monotonicity of $b_n$ suffice to make $\sum a_nb_n$ converge.